# issue while trying to scrape javascript website using htmlunit in Jython

Tags: javascript, python, eclipse, jython, htmlunit

I am trying to scrap a website which has JavaScript in it using Htmlunit module in Jython.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient as WebClient
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion as BrowserVersion

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException

def main():
    webClient = WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME) # creating a new webclient object.
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000)
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(False)
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(False)


    url = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp"
    page = webClient.getPage(url) # getting the url
    name = page.getByXPath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/h1/span")
    print "name:", name[0].asText()

main()
```

Error(s) I am facing :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Eclipse\learnJython\src\HTMLunit_basic.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Eclipse\learnJython\src\HTMLunit_basic.py", line 11, in main
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(False)
AttributeError: 'com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient' object has no attribute 'setThrowExceptionOnScriptError'
```

Issue: Even though i am importing these modules Eclipse is showing that these modules are unused

```
 import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException
 import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException
```

I was importing these modules to bypass the errors arising from JavaScript handling, I want to focus only on some particular scripts and don't want htmlunit to load all scripts. currently htmlunit is loading all scripts ex. facebook plugin which is blocked by our corporate network.

I am new to programming, please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error makes sense. The [`setThrowExceptionOnScriptError`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#getOptions%28%29) is no longer part of the `WebClient`. It has been moved to the [`WebClientOptions`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setThrowExceptionOnScriptError%28boolean%29) class.

So in order to access that method you need to call:

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(False)
```

The same happens with [`setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setThrowExceptionOnScriptError%28boolean%29).